# Redshift : unmatched number of columns between table and file which was generated by spark in parquet format

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, parquet

**Input dataset was generated by pyspark below command,**

```
dfs_ids1.write.parquet('./outputs-parquet/i94-apr16.parquet', mode='overwrite')
```

COPY statement & error message are,

```
COPY staging_ids FROM 's3://sushanth-dend-capstone-files/i94-apr16.parquet/' IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::164084742828:role/dwhRole' FORMAT AS PARQUET ;

S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
  code:      15001
  context:   Task failed due to an internal error. Unmatched number of columns between table and file. Table columns: 23, Data columns: 22, File name: https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sushanth-dend-capstone-files/i94-apr16.parquet/part-00000-6034cb60-860e-4a6c-a86d-6
  query:     1867
  location:  dory_util.cpp:1119
  process:   fetchtask_thread [pid=1331]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

When checking the parquet using S3 "Select from", found that for some JSON sets, column `occup` is missing, this specific column mostly contains "null or STU".

```
 {
        "CoC": 101,
        "CoR": 101,
        "PoE": "BOS",
        "landing_state": "MA",
        "age": 58,
        "visa_issued_in": "TIA",
        "biryear": 1958,
        "gender": "M",
        "airline": "LH",
        "admnum": 2147483647,
        "fltno": "00422",
        "visatype": "B1",
        "arrival_mode": "Air",
        "visit_purpose": "Business",
        "arrival_dt": "2016-04-01",
        "departure_dt": "2016-04-05",
        "DaysinUS": 4,
        "added_to_i94": "2016-04-01",
        "allowed_until": "2016-04-06",
        "entry_exit": "exit",
        "month": 4
    }
```

To verify this column is missing, i read this parquet file in Athena using below parameters,
S3 Path : `s3://sushanth-dend-capstone-files/i94-apr16.parquet/`

Bulk Load of columns : `CoC int, CoR int, PoE string, landing_state string, age int, visa_issued_in string, occup string, biryear int, gender string, airline string, admnum int, fltno string, visatype string, arrival_mode string, visit_purpose string, arrival_dt date, departure_dt date, DaysinUS int, added_to_i94 date, allowed_until date, entry_exit string, month int`

**Athena DDL**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capstone.staging_ids (
  `coc` int,
  `cor` int,
  `poe` string,
  `landing_state` string,
  `age` int,
  `visa_issued_in` string,
  `occup` string,
  `biryear` int,
  `gender` string,
  `airline` string,
  `admnum` int,
  `fltno` string,
  `visatype` string,
  `arrival_mode` string,
  `visit_purpose` string,
  `arrival_dt` date,
  `departure_dt` date,
  `daysinus` int,
  `added_to_i94` date,
  `allowed_until` date,
  `entry_exit` string,
  `month` int 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://sushanth-dend-capstone-files/i94-apr16.parquet/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

When i run the query i could see column 'occup' with STU for some rows.

Question is,

- How to write all the columns from spark dataframe in parquet format
  file ?
- How to load this sort of file into redshift via COPY statement, is parquet not the right format to load into redshift ?